# Is it possible to have different charsets within same database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Total database noob here but I am having an issue with uploading a wordpress site to a Nexcess server. I can do it with no issues on siteground and bluehost but I am missing data when uploading via duplicator and manually. I did the WordPress upgrade to utf8mb4 during the development process of this site and my charset is still set to utf8 in my wp-config file.

Is it possible I have both versions floating around in my database? I had an issue where much of my data was not showing up on the backend but some showing up on front end with question marks but I have managed to resolve that by exporting the database with wp dB migrate to support older versions of mysql. This solved the question marks and that has appeared in the backend again.

Now all I am missing are widgets I made via functions php that I put in my footer. They're all missing their data.

Comment: please fix your tags

Comment: Have you changed the data directly in the DB ? Coz that is not a Best Practice, data is saved in serialization form where characters count is also saved. You should undo the direct changes in the DB and do the changes after the export.

Comment: @Asalan I have not touched any values in the database at this point.  I have one some experimentation testing but none in the currently not working implementation.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress stores many options as "serialized data", which contains both the string content of things and their length. So when you modify the URL and the length changes, then the serialized data is no longer correct, and PHP rejects it.

Comment: Would this be the issue though if both Siteground and Bluehost are able to display all data with no hiccups?

Comment: If you have not modified the data in the DB then the is issue is something else for the missing widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after many red herrings I have solved this.  The issue was as is listed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9076/why-is-my-database-import-losing-text-widget-data) or [here](http://www.themelab.com/why-wordpress-widgets-disappear/), but not as I expected.  The problem is that I didn't pursue this fully since it was working with no issues on SiteGround and Bluehost.

I tried Duplicator, Duplicator PRO, Migrate DB plugin, a manual upload of the database with a search and replace in many different configurations.  All of them left me with the same issues or most of the content replaced but always with the footer missing.  What ended up working for me was using [this php script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).  It was still not a perfect solution because I got it to work on my dev site and on the test site hooked up to a folder on their server set up on my localhost, but I didn't get it to work on the live site.  So I had to, in the end selectively change the links using the php script.  Not elegant, but it got the job done.

None of this really explains to me WHY this was happening though.  If it works so easily on other servers, what is the thing that is messing up on Nexcess?